# Yii2 Variables to be passed in URL - rules not working

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

I have two actions with parameters. I have written two url rules, but only one works at a time. I don't know the issue. These are my acions,
Index action in Site Controller and other one is index action in Product Controller

```
public function actionIndex($language = null) {
    /* some codes */
}

public function actionIndex($id= null) {
    /* some codes */
}

'rules' => [
    '<language>' => 'site/index',
    '<id>' => 'product/index',
  ]
```

The above are my url rules.But only the first rule is working. What is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your rules are ambiguous. `'<language>'` pattern will match every URL, so second rule will never be reached. You should either create different URL structure for these two rules:

```
'rules' => [
    '<language>' => 'site/index',
    'id/<id>' => 'product/index',
],
```

Or use different patters (only literal languages and numerical IDs):

```
'rules' => [
    '<language:[a-z]+>' => 'site/index',
    '<id:\d+>' => 'product/index',
],
```

Comment: Pattern \w+ match numbers too. URL /100 would use the first rule. In your case you would have to place the more strict \d+ pattern first. Also in your first example you have to put 'id/<id>' rule before '<language>' rule.

Comment: @MichalHynčica You're right about `\w+`, I fixed example. But `<language>` will not match `id/123`, because slashes are always treated as params separators, so first example will work too, order of rules should not be relevant here.

Comment: the second rule parameters are not numbers, they are characters too. Both the rules parameters are not numbers. Still only first rule is working. The second url redirects to first action.

Comment: @SaabzCoder First example from my answer should work in that case. Are you sure that URLs like `/id/someid` are handled by first rule?